# ManagedThreadId return same value for 2 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task, c#-5.0

Please consider this code:

```
textBox1.Text = "Enter Thread Current Thread ID Is : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
int result = 0;
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            result = result + i;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Invoke((Action)(() => textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + result.ToString() + " Current Thread ID Is : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString()));
        }
     },CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None);
```

I got this result:

> Enter Thread Current Thread ID Is : 10
>
> 0 Current Thread ID Is : 10
>
> 1 Current Thread ID Is : 10
>
> 3 Current Thread ID Is : 10
>
> 6 Current Thread ID Is : 10
>
> 10 Current Thread ID Is : 10

I ran this code on Windows Form Application. why `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` return same value for UI Thread and Task Thread? Does code inside of `Task` run in a separate thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you did `this.Invoke` you told it to go back to the UI thread. Move `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` outside of the invoke and you will see a different ID for it than the UI thread.

Also if you want to guarantee work is done on a thread pool thread either use `Task.Run` or pass StartNew `TaskScheduler.Default`, if you do not it is possible to have code invoked from `Task.Factory.StartNew` to be accedently run on the UI thread. See [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)